# Strange behavior of tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I have used normal `tabLayout` with `viewpager`. I am using custom tabs   for the `tabLayout`. But some strange behavior happens in tabs.

[image]

As you can see there is space between first two tabs but there is no space between second and third tabs.

Note : In third tab I have set the visibility of arrow `imageview` to gone. **That is not an issue**.

My tablayout screen layout file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTransperent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <com.smartcompliant.views.CustomPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom tabs :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTabTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In java file inflating tabs like :

```
View v =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cust_tabs, null);
tabForm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTabTitle);
tabForm.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.form));
tabForm.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(v);
```

> **So basically two issues :**

1. Space between tabs to be equal.
2. In some small device screen tab gravity center is not working.

Let me know if any code required. Thank you :)

Comment: try adding `android_weight="1";` to `textview` and `imageview` of your  horizontal `LinearLayout `

Comment: @MohammedFarhan Not working.. but it works if i give width to 0 dp but then issue is tabs text will be of two lines not as per design :(

Comment: @Annie try to change **`app:tabMode=""`**

Comment: @NileshRathod Change to what? blank?

Comment: app:tabMode="scrollable" can u try this.

Comment: @Annie use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870017/strange-behavior-of-tabs?noredirect=1#comment86755248_49870017 and make to tablayout **`app:tabMode="scrollable"`**

Comment: @silentsudo scrollable working now first issue solved but now gravity not working it is on the left side now

Comment: @NileshRathod scrollable working now first issue solved but now gravity not working it is on the left side now

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** For fixed tabMode to work, you need to make imageview invisible and not gone.

`GONE` will not take any space in you UI hierarchy, where are `INVISIBLE` will still be there in UI hierarchy but not visible. In your original implementation can you please replace `GONE => INVISIBLE` based on your logic

`MainActivity.java`

```
package in.silentsudo.shoppingcardnavigation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private String[] titles = new String[]{
            "File details", "Select Photo", "Submit"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        final FormDetailsViewAdapter adapter = new FormDetailsViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addPage(new PlaceHolderFragment());
        adapter.addPage(new PlaceHolderFragment());
        adapter.addPage(new PlaceHolderFragment());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_tab, tabLayout, false);
            TextView txtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            txtView.setText(titles[i]);
            txtView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.tab_color_unselected));
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right_unselected);
            if(i == 2) {
                img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(v);
        }

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onTabSelected(tabLayout.getTabAt(0));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        System.out.println("Tab selected : " + tab.getPosition());
        View customView = tab.getCustomView();
        TextView txtView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.tab_color_selected));
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right_selected);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        System.out.println("Tab unselected : " + tab.getPosition());
        View customView = tab.getCustomView();
        TextView txtView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.tab_color_unselected));
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right_unselected);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        System.out.println("Tab reselected : " + tab.getPosition());
    }
}

class FormDetailsViewAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> list;

    public FormDetailsViewAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addPage(Fragment fragment) {
        list.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Fragment " + position;
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="in.silentsudo.shoppingcardnavigation.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`item_tab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="This is text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right_selected" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`PlaceHolderFragment.java`

```
public class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_place_holder, container, false);
    }
}
```

`fragment_place_holder.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is place holder fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`ic_right_selected.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:height="18dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="18dp">
    <path android:fillColor="#1DE9B6" android:pathData="M8.59,16.34l4.58,-4.59 -4.58,-4.59L10,5.75l6,6 -6,6z"/>
</vector>
```

`ic_right_unselected.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="18dp"
    android:height="18dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#BDBDBD"
        android:pathData="M8.59,16.34l4.58,-4.59 -4.58,-4.59L10,5.75l6,6 -6,6z" />
</vector>
```

`colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="tab_color_selected">#1DE9B6</color>
    <color name="tab_color_unselected">#BDBDBD</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Not working still the space issue.. i am ok with scrollable.. just tell me the way to center the tabs in all screens.

Comment: Can you share your, custom layout for tab?

Comment: I have added in question.. "Custom tabs :" is the file

Comment: try making linear layout match parent and give layout gravity centre, remember use INVISIBLE for image and not GONE

Comment: @Annie answer added please take a look

Comment: Still not working. Thank you for help. I got this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9kPt.png

Comment: Your font size is too big annie reduce and see and then adjust according to needt last option is scrollable, becuase u cannt fit that size at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

custom tab layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTabTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

set tab icon

```
  public void setTab(){
        View v =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tabForm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTabTitle);
        tabForm.setText("Fill details");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(v);


        View v2 =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tabForm2 = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.tvTabTitle);
        tabForm2.setText("Select photo");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(v2);

        View v3 =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tabForm3 = (TextView) v3.findViewById(R.id.tvTabTitle);
        tabForm3.setText("submit");
        ImageView imageView=v3.findViewById(R.id.ivArrow);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(v3);
    }
```

Comment: still the same output.. tabs are on left side not getting centered

Comment: @Annie test case try to set `android:layout_gravity="center"`